# I am lost with the Linq Shorthand IN clause

Tags: linq, razor, shorthand

I have searched and found lots of almost understandable answers but either I am totally bonkers or they just don't fit in my LINQ Shorthand syntax. I looked at all the "similar duplicate questions" . . . I used The Google too. Maybe I just don't know how to ask the question.

My code to return only 3 cities for now out of a table of Cities. My shorthand works for CityID == 1 but I don't know how to reference the array I inserted with 3 different cities: 1,2,3. It would not scale very nice if I were to use the CityID==1 || CityID==2 || CityID==3  syntax and in the future planned to add 10-100 more cities.

```
      public IList<Models.Cities> Cities { get;set; }
    
        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Cities = (IList<Models.Cities>)await _context.tblCities.ToListAsync();
            
            var citylist = new int[] { 1, 2, 4 };

            Cities = Cities.Where(x => x.CityID==1).ToList();
    
        }
```

**BIG EDIT/ANSWER:**
Svyatoslav Danyliv's solution worked and here is how I use it. I can stack all sorts of calculation or criteria building one piece at a time rather that one huge query that is a "work or doesn't". Easy to take out or add the little pieces I put together. Many times these Lambda expressions take values from what is sent to OnGetAsync().

```
    public async Task OnGetAsync(string blah, int blahblah, int yadayada) 
{
     var citylist = new int[] { 1, 2, 4 };
     var query = _context.tblCities.AsQueryable();
    
        query = query.Where(c => citylist.Contains(c.CityID));
         
        //SOME CALCULATIONS HERE
        query = query.Where(c => c.xxx == blah);
        
       //SOME CALCULATIONS HERE       
        query = query.Where(c => c.yyyy <= blahblah);
        //ADD MORE  HERE
       query = query.Where(c => c.ooo= yadayada);   
 
        //AND FINALLY OPEN THE RAZOR PAGE
        Cities = await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

Does this increase the overhead? Not sure, you tell me. But when it comes time to scale I could put all the different calculations and criteria in to one honking huge query. Of course I will probably ask Svyatoslav Danyliv thank you very much!

Comment: I believe you are looking for `.Where(x => cityList.Contains(x.CityID))`? That should translate into something like `WHERE x.CityId IN (@p1, @p2, @p3)` in the generated SQL, where cityList values are passed in as parameters @p1, @p2, and @p3.

Comment: What do you mean by  "LINQ Shorthand syntax"? And which type of LINQ is this? What is the ORM, and its version?

Comment: @GertArnold I think I am referring to Lambda Expressions used in Linq queries. It is a shorthand. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq

Comment: @GertArnold With this shorthand I can stack all sorts of easy to understand criteria into the final call to open the Razor page

Comment: @TN I could not make your syntax work. I had to use this:     var query = _context.tblCities.AsQueryable(); as my accepted answer shows. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering should be done before materialization using `Contains`.

```cs
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    var citylist = new int[] { 1, 2, 4 };
    var query = _context.tblCities.AsQueryable();

    if (citylist.Length > 0) // conditional querying
        query = query.Where(c => citylist.Contains(c.CityID))

    Cities = await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Wow, that worked. Not sure how but thank you very much!!!